# Get list using Join Issue

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to grab all users joined with Company

```
var users = CreateObject<User>();
var companies = CreateObject<Company>();

var companyUsers = users
    .Where(u => u.IsEmployee)
    .Join(companies, u => u.UserId, c => c.UserId, (u, c) => u.UserId)
    .ToList();
```

Problem: I'm trying to return companyUsers which is of type List and my method's return type is List that this code is in but I get the error that List cannot be converted to List  when I do a return companyUsers for this method.

I figured it's just a syntax error in that LINQ is trying to return a different type due to a syntax issue in my query that I cannot see.

Comment: basically it's saying I can't assign the returned LINQ type to my companyUsers and company users is a List<User>

Comment: That would have been useful information *to actually be in the question*.

Comment: so I'm returning companyUsers from my method...or trying to at least.  The return type of my method that this code is contained in is List<User>.  When I try to do return companyUsers, I get an error that List<int> cannot be converted to List<User>  But if my method return type is List<User> why would I be getting this?  I assumed my query is wrong.

Comment: well I figured this was a stupid simple question that I was blinded by and thought it's probably a very basic syntax fix that I'm apparently blind to today so I didn't think it needed a whole lot of explanation.  I still think the query definition must be wrong in terms of syntax here...that's what I'm asking.

Comment: as you can see my past posts are usually very detailed...just didn't think this needed it and if it does, now you are getting it.  Just give me a chance good God.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: Sure, I'll give you a chance. If we get flags on your posts and comments *again*, you know what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> basically it's saying I can't assign the returned LINQ type to my companyUsers and company users is a `List<User>`

You are not selecting a user, you are selecting a *user ID* in your query. The output then is a `List<X>`, where `X` is the type of `UserId` (I presume it's an int or some other basic type).

To fix this issue to get a `List<User>`, change your join to produce a different output.

```
.Join(companies, u => u.UserId, c => c.UserId, (u, c) => u)
.ToList();
```

Comment: thanks and do you know how I could add an additional check to this...so in other words I've tried to add u => u.UserId and I wanted to also check that u.SomethingElse = c.Something  but cant' figure where to add this for this lambda syntax.  I want to base this on further company / user field matching

Comment: Ex. `u => new { u.UserId, u.SomethingElse }`